# android studio return specific array value when markeronclick

Tags: android

i m new here and so as android. this is my first android exprience and my first post here. Please correct me if i have make any mistake.

How can i return the specific value of placeName, address, when the specific infowindow is onclick?

here is my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getResults().size(); i++) {

Double lat=response.body().getResults().get(i).getGeometry().getLocation().getLat();
                        Double lng = response.body().getResults().get(i).getGeometry().getLocation().getLng();

final String placeName = response.body().getResults().get(i).getName();
final String address = response.body().getResults().get(i).getAddress();

final MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
// Position of Marker on Map
markerOptions.position(latLng);
// Adding Title to the Marker
markerOptions.title("hello" + placeName + address);
// Adding Marker to the Camera.
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
// Marker marker1 = marker;
mHashmap.put(marker, i);}
```

this is the onclick function

```
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
         public MarkerOptions MarkerOptions;
         public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
              TextView myawesometextview=   (TextView)findViewById(textView);
              int pos = mHashmap.get(marker);
              Log.i("position of arraylist", pos+"");
              //myawesometextview.setText("i wanna display value of address and placename of a specific marker here ");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can initialize `String placename;` `String address;`
as global then you can access them anywhere inside your activity